# How to deploy Fedora Commons 4.1 on WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, fedora, wildfly, wildfly-8, fedora-commons

I am trying to deploy Fedora Commons 4.1.1 on WildFly but having some trouble. I have downloaded fcrepo-webapp-4.1.1.war from https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/FF/Downloads and deployed on WildFly.

After it is deployed, when I direct to localhost:8080/fedora/rest it throws the exception below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You did not supply enough values to fill path parameters at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilder.buildFromValues(ResteasyUriBuilder.java:724) at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilder.build(ResteasyUriBuilder.java:717)  at org.fcrepo.http.commons.api.rdf.HttpResourceConverter.toDomain(HttpResourceConverter.java:182) ...
```

Could anyone help me with deploying Fedora Commons to WildFly?